# on scroll animation animated but then fades out on safari, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, css

The code works but for some reason in Safari after its animated it fades slightly and I'm going crazy not being able to figure it out. I would like for the animation to stay on full opacity after it has animated in on scroll, but for some reason Safari makes it fade slightly after the animation. Can anyone help please?

Html:

```
<div class="js-scroll slide-left column content-column-title scrolled"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
```

The Css and Keyframes:

```
.titleOpacity {
        opacity: 0.333333;
        top: 47%!important;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
        -o-transition: all .4s linear;
        transition: all .4s linear;
        -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
        filter: blur(2px);
        }
    .js-scroll {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
        -o-transition: opacity 250ms;
        transition: opacity 250ms;
        }
    
    .js-scroll.scrolled {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    
    .scrolled.fade-in {
        -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out both;
        animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out both;
        }
    
    .scrolled.fade-in-bottom {
        -webkit-animation: fade-in-bottom 1s ease-in-out both;
        animation: fade-in-bottom 1s ease-in-out both;
        }
    
    .scrolled.fade-in-bottom-delay {
        -webkit-animation: fade-in-bottom-delay 1s ease-in-out both;
        animation: fade-in-bottom-delay 1s ease-in-out both;
        }
    .scrolled.slide-left {
        -webkit-animation: slide-in-left 1s ease-in-out both;
        animation: slide-in-left 1s ease-in-out both;
        }
    .scrolled.slide-right {
        -webkit-animation: slide-in-right 1s ease-in-out both;
        animation: slide-in-right 1s ease-in-out both;
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes slide-in-left {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5s0px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @keyframes slide-in-left {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5s0px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes slide-in-right {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
        transform: translateX(50px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @keyframes slide-in-right {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
        transform: translateX(50px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bottom {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @keyframes fade-in-bottom {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bottom-delay {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @keyframes fade-in-bottom-delay {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
        from {
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
    
        @keyframes fade-in {
        from {
        opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
        opacity: 1;
        }
        }
```

The Js code:

```
    const scrollElements = document.querySelectorAll(".js-scroll");
    const elementInView = (el, dividend = 1) => {
    const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return (elementTop <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) / dividend);
        };
    const elementOutofView = (el) => {
    const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return (elementTop > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight));
        };
    const displayScrollElement = (element) => {
    element.classList.add("scrolled");
        };
    const hideScrollElement = (element) => {
    element.classList.remove("scrolled");
        };
    const handleScrollAnimation = () => {
    scrollElements.forEach((el) => {
    if (elementInView(el, 1.25)) {
    displayScrollElement(el);
    } else if (elementOutofView(el)) {
    hideScrollElement(el)}
    })
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    handleScrollAnimation();
    });
```

Comment: Need to format codes

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with the code provided, do you have a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you know better code for the js to do the function that I want, I'd happily learn whats would be better practice.